# Incrementing a Cell in Excel which is associated with different columns and formulas and I wish to record the results of each increment carried out

Tags: excel

I am looking to find a solution for the following:
I am trying to obtain the maximum revenue that can be earned by incrementing a cell in this spr[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZkA0.png)eadsheet below, recording the results obtained from each increment and simply finding the maximum value of the list of recorded values from incrementing.

I am focusing on the cell J4 (Rev if New floor set) which contains the following formula [=SUMIF(B4:B24,">"&I4,H4:H24)] which computes a sum of the values in the column ‘Seller receives after Rev Share if floor increased’ that correspond to the rows where ‘Buyer_Bid > Minimum to be paid by Buyer’.
The Cell ‘Minimum to be paid by Buyer’(&I4) contains the formula [=F4/0.84] where the column F contains the Floor_Price. to be set (What I want to increment to find maximum solution (Overall Revenue).

The Cells in the column ‘Seller receives after Rev Share if floor increased’ contain the following formula ‘[=IF(E4>F4,E4,G4)] which places in the instance where the rows in column E ( Seller receives after Rev share) > rows in column F (New_Floorprice) the corresponding rows where this statement is true from column E and places them in Column H and for the instance that this condition fails it puts the corresponding to the rows failing the condition from Column G into H.

The Cells in the column ‘Buyer_Bid’ simply contain values which were imported and not created within the spreadsheet.

The columns which make up the final figure ‘Rev if new floor set’ depend on the New_Floorprice which I want to increment to find out which floor price results in the most revenue(Overall Revenue = Rev if New Floor Set – Rev Today)

I was hoping to be able to automatically increment Cell B1 by increments of 0.001 which then would change all the corresponding values in the spreadsheet as I have the Column F = B1 and then record the results for ‘Rev if New Floor Set’, ‘Rev Today’ and ‘Overall Rev’ for each increment carried out so I can simply obtain the optimal Floor price that produces maximum revenue. However 'Rev Today' solution will stay constant as the column that the formula is made up of was imported and left as is.
I have tried using solver for this problem by setting the objective to column L4 and choosing to maximise changing the variable cell B1 with the constraint of L4>=0 however kept getting a different result when I manually changed to optimal floor price B1.

I am trying to make this as clear as possible but please let me know if it is hard to understand. Also I have never used VBA so a solution which doesn't involve VBA would be great please. I have a link to an image of the spreadsheet below.

It would be much appreciated if I Could get some help with this please.
Many thanks,

Comment: Sorry the link has appeared to have vanished so here you go: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QZkA0.png

Comment: `automatically increment Cell B1` `doesn't involve VBA` To do anything automatically, you'd need VBA. This seems like homework and it's not terribly difficult to find optimal floor by hand.

Comment: You didn't say what version of excel you were using but look up [data tables](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-onevariable-data-table-in-excel-21.html) (found under data>What-if Analysis>Data tables) in excel 2013.  It sounds like what you want.